# How can I install Ubuntu from a Kubuntu installation?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I've installed [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/) in a laptop but I like to use [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) instead. Is there some way to install Ubuntu without having to reinstall the whole thing from scratch?

I've been trying to find documentation about this on the net but nobody seems to have tried to "migrate" between the [different derivatives of Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/derivatives). Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The virtual package "ubuntu-desktop" is all you need to install. That will bring in GNOME and the rest of the Ubuntu desktop for you. It will also leave Kubuntu installed. Cleansing your computer of Kubuntu isn't an easy task.

[This guy](http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/puregnome) seems to have cooked up the list of everything Kubuntu has and Ubuntu doesn't:

> sudo apt-get remove akregator amarok amarok-common apport-qt ark cdrdao dolphin dontzap dragonplayer exiv2 foomatic-db-gutenprint gdebi-kde gnupg-agent gtk2-engines-qtcurve gwenview hpijs-ppds ijsgutenprint install-package jockey-kde k3b k3b-data kaddressbook kamera kate kde-icons-oxygen kde-printer-applet kde-style-qtcurve kde-window-manager kde-zeroconf kdebase-bin kdebase-data kdebase-plasma kdebase-runtime kdebase-runtime-bin-kde4 kdebase-runtime-data kdebase-runtime-data-common kdebase-workspace-bin kdebase-workspace-data kdebase-workspace-libs4+5 kdebluetooth kdegraphics-strigi-plugins kdelibs-bin kdelibs-data kdelibs4c2a kdelibs5 kdelibs5-data kdemultimedia-kio-plugins kdepasswd kdepim-kresources kdepim-strigi-plugins kdepim-wizards kdepimlibs-data kdepimlibs5 kdeplasma-addons kdeplasma-addons-data kdesudo kdm kfind khelpcenter4 klipper kmag kmail kmix kmousetool knotes konqueror konqueror-nsplugins konqueror-plugin-searchbar konsole kontact kopete korganizer kpackagekit krdc krfb ksnapshot ksysguard ksysguardd ksystemlog ktimetracker ktorrent ktorrent-data kubuntu-artwork-usplash kubuntu-default-settings kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-docs kubuntu-konqueror-shortcuts kuser kvkbd kwalletmanager language-selector-qt libakonadiprivate1 libao2 libaudio2 libavahi-qt3-1 libboost-program-options1.35.0 libclucene0ldbl libdbus-qt-1-1c2 libeet1 libexiv2-5 libflac++6 libgeoip1 libk3b3 libk3b3-extracodecs libkcddb4 libkdecorations4 libkdepim4 libkexiv2-7 libkholidays4 libkipi6 libkleo4 libkonq5 libkonq5-templates libkpgp4 libksieve4 libkwineffects1 libloudmouth1-0 liblua50 liblualib50 libmad0 libmimelib4 libmodplug0c2 libmpcdec3 libmsn0.1 libmysqlclient15off libokularcore1 libpackagekit-glib11 libpackagekit-qt11 libphonon4 libplasma3 libpoppler-qt4-3 libpq5 libqca2 libqca2-plugin-ossl libqedje0 libqimageblitz4 libqt3-mt libqt4-assistant libqt4-core libqt4-dbus libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-webkit libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libqzion0 libraptor1 librasqal1 librdf0 libsearchclient0 libsoprano4 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libstrigihtmlgui0 libstrigiqtdbusclient0 libvncserver0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-xv0 libxine1 libxine1-bin libxine1-console libxine1-misc-plugins libxine1-x libzip1 mysql-common okular okular-extra-backends openoffice.org-kde openoffice.org-style-crystal oxygen-cursor-theme packagekit packagekit-backend-apt phonon phonon-backend-xine pinentry-gtk2 pinentry-qt4 plasma-widget-network-manager plasma-widget-quickaccess python-dev python-kde4 python-packagekit python-plasma python-qt4 python-qt4-common python-qt4-dbus python-sip4 python2.6-dev qt4-qtconfig quassel quassel-data raptor-utils redland-utils software-properties-kde soprano-daemon speedcrunch strigi-client strigi-daemon system-config-printer-kde systemsettings ttf-dejavu ttf-dejavu-extra update-manager-kde update-notifier-kde && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Cleansing kubuntu is a bit kludgy (with missing package-lists). If you choose to not uninstall then you're given the option if you want to use gnome (gwm) or kde (kwm), and it works nicely for me even though kubuntu is still installed.

Comment: gnome's wm isn't gwm, it's either metacity or compiz. Did you mean GDM or KDM?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I meant you had to choose between GDM/KDM when installing ubuntu-desktop given that you haven't uninstalled kubuntu-desktop (I was only looking at the first letter in the three letter acronyms it presented). Anyhow, that means the installation isn't non-interactive (sorry for the double negation there).

Comment: It would be great if someone wrote a program to find the unnecessary packages.

Answer (score 2):

To give a shorter answer - From the command line, do

```
$ sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop
```

(I won't go into GUI ways of doing this as this site is meant to be for server admins who ought to be comfortable at the command line).